# manually require 'Bootsy' in assets pipeline Rails 4 application.css vs application.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, wysiwyg, require

I'm using a WYSIWYG called Bootsy. docs here: http://volmer.github.io/bootsy/
I did this command and got:

```
$ rails generate bootsy:install
route  mount Bootsy::Engine => '/bootsy', as: 'bootsy'
  create  config/locales/bootsy.en.yml
  insert  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  not found  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css not found. You must manually require Bootsy in your assets pipeline.
  create  config/initializers/bootsy.rb
```

In my Rails app I do have a file called application.css.scss   so the only reason the install couldn't find the file was because of the .scss   I'm wondering how to best address this issue.

My first guess was to do this inside my application.css.scss file:

```
require 'bootsy'
```

but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do

```
*= require_bootsy
or
*= require 'bootsy'
```

or if I should just add an application.css file inside the pipeline that way it doesn't give me problems. Would that be bad to have an application.css AND an application.css.scss file inside my stylesheets folder?

Comment: add "*= require bootsy" to your application.css.scss just before "*/" on top of the file

Answer (score 3):

According to the gem source you should use  `*= require bootsy`

Here's the relevant code from https://github.com/volmer/bootsy/blob/master/lib/generators/bootsy/install_generator.rb

```
{
   original: 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.css',
   skip_if: 'require bootsy',
   content: "\n *= require bootsy",
   position: {
      after: '*= require_self'
   }
}
```